# Windows 7 : uptime, last user logged in time and date, last rebooted

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a command or a GUI tool in Windows 7 to get the following?

1. uptime
2. last user logged in time and date
3. machine last rebooted

Comment: 1) Up Time is [on **task manager**](http://superuser.com/a/523728/139292)

Answer (score 18):

Go to command prompt (type `cmd` into start menu) and enter **`quser`**. It shows the dates of all [current] users' logins. `administrator` will show the time the computer was last booted.

This will still display the correct logon times even if the workstation's screen has been locked some time during the session.

<sub>You may then use a net [date calculator](http://www.mathcats.com/explore/elapsedtime.html) to figure out *how long* they (or the computer) has been on.</sub>

Comment: Not work for me. `'quser' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: reading [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754583.aspx) it looks like you can type **`query user`** as an [equivalent alternative](http://ss64.com/nt/query-user.html). Although maybe your version of Windows doesn't include it. Im on x64 win7

Comment: `query user` doesn't work either. I'm on win8 64 bit

Comment: Just tried it on my tablet; still works (8.1 Pro). Maybe you have [basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions), sorry, I don't know why you don't have it

Answer (score 16):

I know that login/logout times can be found under the `Security` section of `Windows Logs` in **Event Viewer**. It's worth looking around on Event Viewer to find other information you require.

Found in: *Control Panel (Classic view) **>** Administrative Tools*

*or* hit start and type "event viewer" into the search.

[This may also help.](http://blogs.howtogeek.com/mysticgeek/2008/11/10/easily-determine-windows-uptime-in-vista-or-xp/)

Answer (score 11):

Surely when you know 1 you can work out 3?

You can find out the uptime from the command line using this command:

```
net statistics server | find "Statistics since"
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Start *Command Prompt*.
2. Enter `cd C:\Windows\system32` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Then write `quser` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

Using ‘Net user’ command we can find the last login time of a user. The exact command is given below.

```
**net user  **username** | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"**
```

Change username with username of your PC.

***Example:***
To find the last login time of the computer administrator

```
**C:\> net user administrator | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"
Last logon                   6/30/2010 10:02 AM
C:>**
```

and this would be helpfull

**`net user  username`**

Comment: with administrator it shows nothing,  but with my username is says "The user name could not be found"

Comment: This will only work on local accounts (e.g. Administrator, Guest), not network logins

Comment: It works for domain account if you add `/domain`. For example `net user nameoftheuser /domain | findstr /C:"Last logon"`

Answer (score 3):

the task manager will show up time under the performance tab

Answer (score 1):

Here is all the points you are looking for:
You can download the script and GUI.
You need to use as administrator Level.
 You also need to create computers.txt file under C:\
That is what his script say and save whatever pc/servers you want to query.

I found this absolutely useful, Full credit to Gandalf50. Link is here >>>
[ScriptCentre Gurus](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Display-computers-status-c8ff289d)

Comment: welcome to superuser, where do you download the gui from?, what does the script say? Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: click the link as I mentioned above "ScriptCentre Gurus". There is every details explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about last user, but uptime/reboot, you can use the following gadget:

http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=9edd60d7-5810-44b4-a72e-b3416de5758b

Don't worry about the image quality, the little screenshot is really distorted, but i've been using it for years now on Vista, and 7, and it has been working beautifully.

It shows you the time your computer has been up in the format:

w days
x hours
y minutes
z seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try [System Up Time Monitor 5.5](http://download.cnet.com/System-Up-Time-Monitor/3000-2094_4-10641146.html)

```
This program will display the system started Date & Time , how long the pc is running now etc. You can ask the program to shutdown the pc, restart, hibernate etc when a perticuler time reached.
Note: The program can monitor up to 49days.
Supports Windows 200 / XP/ vista.
```

Should work with Windows 7. But haven't tested yet.