# Windows 10 mysteriously boots up.. WHY?

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 machine would sometimes automatically boots up at night for no apparent reason. Is there some sort of log that I can check that would give an explanation?

Comment: that's because of the BIOS and not Windows. In BIOS setup you can see the option to start the PC after power failure and the alarm timer to automatically start the PC at some point of time

Comment: You could check my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1350900/926024 to get the exact time of the boot. If it's always the same time there might be some script, BIOS or WOL feature that triggers the startup at a specific time. Other answers in the question I've linked might also show you more details about how the start-up happened.

Comment: Do you use Shut Down, or sleep (or hibernate) ?  Is this a laptop, and do you close the lid when you're done with it?  Windows the OS can come up from sleep but not from full shutdown.  As others have mentioned, if it's fully shut down, then the BIOS is waking it up, usually from LAN or BIOS schedule.

Answer (score 2):

1. Report information about the last event that woke the computer: `powercfg /lastwake`
2. Lists devices that are user-configurable to wake the system from a sleep state: `POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_programmable`
3. Lists devices that are currently configured to wake the system from any sleep state: `POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_armed`
4. Returns all devices that support waking the system from any sleep state: `POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_from_any`

After finding culprit maybe you can remove the SW or HW. If not r[eference @Alex's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1354219/160219) to disable wake timers in power settings GUI

Links:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn898599(v=vs.85).aspx https://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html

Answer (score 1):

To prevent windows 10 from automatic wake up one need to disable wake up timers in:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options -> Change plan settings
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the multiple reasons could be the [Wake-On-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) feature.

Is there any mechanism in your network that would send out Wake-On-LAN packages? 
Also is your computer configured to respond to such packets?

Comment: Confirmation of this is easy; disconnect your LAN before you turn in for the night. No LAN, no signal can be received from the LAN to wake the PC.