# Get last boot/start time on Windows

Tags: windows, boot, reboot

I want to know when the Windows PC (Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019) was restarted. Today I tried it on my freshly booted machine (10 minutes ago) and I got the 17th August 2021 at 11:51:26 PM. So it seems the PC was hibernating, while being completely turned off (without power!).

How do I get the last time the PC was restarted? I tried with this

Command line:

> systeminfo /s localhost

PowerShell:

> Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime

but they are giving me the wrong information.

Comment: What wrong information are the commands giving you? Why do you consider 17th August 2021 at 11:51:26 PM as the correct date?

Comment: I want to get the 1st September 2021 as start/boot date. The 17th August may be correct for Windows itself, but it isn't the date I'm looking for. Don't know how it is called correctly (for me it's the boot date).

Comment: So both commands give 17th August as last bootup time?

Comment: Yes, as well as task manager is showing the old date

Comment: The returned information is not wrong. It just means that the computer was not completely shutdown since 17th August.

Comment: @harrymc: yeah I got that, but how do I get the date/time when the computer was restarted the last time (regardless of Windows decides to hibernate "internally")? And I mean a restart for the user (not for the OS)! This is e.g. when you turn your computer on and off or the system was restarted by the user or the system crashed and restarted.

Comment: Use the command from this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1631429/855367)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: yeah this brings two entries with the last start ups. Thanks! You could provide an answer if you want :-)

Comment: Thanks but It's better if you upvote the person who wrote that answer :)

Comment: already happened :-) didn't saw the question was closed (only after reload)